# Android Wear 2D Picker, how to control which column to go to when viewing car

Tags: android, wear-os

I am trying to implement pages of cards using 2D Picker. 
how can I show the following:
if I am on column1, when swiping up or down, it will go back to column0;
and if I am on column2, when swiping up or down, it will stay at column2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `GridPagerAdapter` can override `getCurrentColumnForRow()`:

> Returns the column to arrive at when navigating vertically to the specified row.
>
> The default implementation simply returns 0.

Therefore you can write something like:

```
public int getCurrentColumnForRow (int row, int currentColumn) {
  return currentColumn;
}
```

if all of your rows have the same number of columns or something slightly more complicated if they don't:

```
public int getCurrentColumnForRow (int row, int currentColumn) {
  return Math.min(getColumnCount(row)-1, currentColumn);
}
```

Comment: When I override getCurrentColumnForRow(int row, int currentColumn), the app crashes when I slide to the third column (not even got the chance to move up or down).  If I don't override getCurrentColumnFor, it works fine.

Comment: and the crash was caused by IndexOutOfBound: Length = 2; Index =2; size of the pages is 3 x 3.

Comment: Ah, yes it should be `getColumnCount(row)-1` rather than just `getColumnCount(row)`. I've updated my answer.

Comment: although it's crashing, it's not doing what I want.  I was trying:  if (row == 1) 
    return 0; 
else return currentColumn; but it crashes; even just return currentColumn crashes too

Comment: If you know always returning `0` (per the default implementation) doesn't crash, it should be easy to iterate on what you return until you get the behavior you want. Double check that `getColumnCount()` is returning the right values and feel free to include source code in your question - we can't see what you are doing to know if there is a problem elsewhere in your `GridPagerAdapter`.

Comment: I want to make correction to my last comment.  I actually tried if (currentColumn== 1) return 0; else return currentColumn; The crash is at getRowCount(), after fixing it, it's working what I want.

Comment: Great! Make sure to accept the answer if this helped answer your question :)